# Using SubQuery in case Satement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm tasked with creating a query to pull Employee information from today's date. Right now I have test data that returns one record for each of the conditions below. What if the subquery returns multiple records? Is there a better way to write this?

Query Employee_Master.

I need to display the Name, ID, Type, and Date.

Type is going to be a column created by a case statement.

'NEW' when Start_Date = Today_Date
'TERMINATED' when Terminate_Date = Today_Date
'EXTENDED' when Start_Date<>Today_Date and Terminate_Date<>Today_Date and the same record exists in employee_reference table for today's date. 
'NAME CHANGED' if the user is 'EXTENDED' and exists in Name_Change table

```
SELECT Name, ID, Date,
Type = CASE
WHEN Start_Date = Today_Date THEN 'NEW'
WHEN Terminate_Date = Today_Date THEN 'TERMINATED'
WHEN ID = (SELECT A.ID FROM Employee_Master AS A
INNER JOIN Employee_Reference AS B on B.ID = A.ID
WHERE DATE = GETDATE()) THEN 'EXTENDED'
WHEN ID = (SELECT A.ID FROM Employee_Master AS A
INNER JOIN Name_Change AS B ON B.ID = A.ID 
WHERE Create_Date = GETDATE()) THEN 'Name Changed'
END
FROM Employee_Master
WHERE Today_Date = GETDATE()
```

Comment: Move the INNER JOIN to the FROM or  use LEFT JOIN and keep just the  B.ID = A.ID conditions in the CASE

Comment: Is ID a Primary Key on Employee_Master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure where all your dates are coming from in the subselects since they aren't aliased, but here is conceptually what I would try:

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    ID, 
    Date,
    Type = CASE
            WHEN Start_Date = Today_Date THEN 'NEW'
            WHEN Terminate_Date = Today_Date THEN 'TERMINATED'
            WHEN (SELECT MAX(DATE)
                    FROM Employee_Reference ER on ER.ID = EM.ID) = GETDATE() THEN 'EXTENDED'
            WHEN ID = (SELECT MAX(Create_Date)
                        FROM Name_Change AS NC ON NC.ID = EM.ID) = GETDATE() THEN 'Name Changed'
           END
FROM Employee_Master EM
WHERE Today_Date = GETDATE()
```

Essentially, this eliminates the extra selection of ID from employee_master, since you are already selecting from that, and selects the max date from the table targeted in the sub-select.  You'll only get one back that way, and if it matches today's date then it will satisfy the case statement.

Note that the above assumes your original query gets the entire population.  However, I suspect you might want to actually include employee_reference and name_change as outer joins in your FROM statement and then filter down to everything from the current date in your WHERE statement - something like:

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    ID, 
    Date,
    CASE
        WHEN Start_Date = Today_Date THEN 'NEW'
        WHEN Terminate_Date = Today_Date THEN 'TERMINATED'
        WHEN ID = (SELECT A.ID FROM Employee_Master AS A
        INNER JOIN Employee_Reference AS B on B.ID = A.ID
        WHERE DATE = GETDATE()) THEN 'EXTENDED'
        WHEN ID = (SELECT A.ID FROM Employee_Master AS A
        INNER JOIN Name_Change AS B ON B.ID = A.ID 
        WHERE Create_Date = GETDATE()) THEN 'Name Changed'
    END AS Type
FROM Employee_Master EM
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee_Reference ER
        ON ER.ID = EM.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Name_Change NC
        ON NC.ID = EM.ID
WHERE 
 Today_Date = GETDATE()
 OR DATE = GETDATE() --note: you'll need to alias date since there appears to be more than one column named this
 OR Create_Date = GETDATE()
```

Comment: Thank you, I think thats pointing me to the right path. They added a few tweaks and to their request. Other than that I think I should be set!